# How to achieve this calculation using javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net

First of all thanks for viewing this question.Now,let me show you what I want

[image]

as you could see there are two columns in my table..
Now, if someone put 30 or 300 then the table will look like this

[image]

Basically,the calculation will go like this way.

Now, I am doing this calculation using javascript and I don't figure out how to get this.

Here, is my code that I have tried..

```
//NOTE: This is an asp grid
        //enterdValue = the value I am putting.
        function FirstPriority(sender, eventArgs) {
            debugger;
            var loop = true;
            var loopcounter = 0;
            if (isNaN($find("<%= txt_payingAmt.ClientID %>").get_textBoxValue())) {
                eventArgs.set_cancel(true);
            }
            else {
                let enterdValue = parseFloat($find("<%= txt_payingAmt.ClientID %>").get_textBoxValue());
                var grid = $find("<%=rgv_INVList.ClientID%>");
                //loop through..
                for (var row = 0; row < grid.MasterTableView.get_dataItems().length ; row++) {
                    var remainingTot = 0;
                    loopcounter += 1;
                    var rowTotAmount = parseFloat(grid.MasterTableView.getCellByColumnUniqueName(grid.MasterTableView.get_dataItems()[row], "GrandTotal").innerHTML);
                    var alreadyPaid = parseFloat(grid.MasterTableView.getCellByColumnUniqueName(grid.MasterTableView.get_dataItems()[row], "PayingAmount").innerHTML);
                    if (loopcounter == 1) {
                        if ((alreadyPaid + enterdValue) <= rowTotAmount) {
                            grid.MasterTableView.getCellByColumnUniqueName(grid.MasterTableView.get_dataItems()[row], "PayingAmount").innerHTML = alreadyPaid + enterdValue;
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                    else if (loopcounter > 1) {
                        if ((alreadyPaid + enterdValue) == rowTotAmount) {
                            grid.MasterTableView.getCellByColumnUniqueName(grid.MasterTableView.get_dataItems()[row], "PayingAmount").innerHTML = rowTotAmount;
                            break;
                        }
                        else {
                            grid.MasterTableView.getCellByColumnUniqueName(grid.MasterTableView.get_dataItems()[row], "PayingAmount").innerHTML = remainingTot;
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                    else {
                        if (loop) {
                            remainingTot = (alreadyPaid + enterdValue) - rowTotAmount;
                            grid.MasterTableView.getCellByColumnUniqueName(grid.MasterTableView.get_dataItems()[row], "PayingAmount").innerHTML = rowTotAmount;
                            if (grid.MasterTableView.get_dataItems().length != loopcounter) {
                                if (remainingTot <= grid.MasterTableView.getCellByColumnUniqueName(grid.MasterTableView.get_dataItems()[row + 1], "PayingAmount").innerHTML) {
                                    grid.MasterTableView.getCellByColumnUniqueName(grid.MasterTableView.get_dataItems()[row + 1], "PayingAmount").innerHTML = alreadyPaid + enterdValue;
                                    loop = false;
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
```

Let me tell you what these variables does,

- enterdValue = This will get an input from user.
- grid = rendered as table and to loop thru I need this.
- rowTotAmount = TotalInvAmount as shown in grid.
- alreadyPaid = paidAmount as shown in grid.

Help needed to achieve this :) 
Thanks & regards

Comment: So you want to carry the remaining amount to the next line so you can see how much someone has paid?

Comment: exactly that sir.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have figured out to solve it :) hence posting it here.

```
function FirstPriority(args) {
                debugger;
                resetGrid();
                var paidAmount, totAmount, paidAmountHdn, payingAmount, remainingBalance = 0;
                payingAmount = parseFloat(args.value);
                var grid = $find("<%=rgv_INVList.ClientID%>");
                if (!isNaN(payingAmount)) {
                    remainingBalance = payingAmount;
                    for (var row = 0; row < grid.MasterTableView.get_dataItems().length ; row++) {
                        paidAmount = parseFloat(grid.MasterTableView.get_dataItems()[row]._element.cells[5].innerText); //grid.MasterTableView.get_dataItems()[0]._element.cells[1].innerText
                        totAmount = parseFloat(grid.MasterTableView.get_dataItems()[row]._element.cells[4].innerText);
                        paidAmountHdn = parseFloat(grid.MasterTableView.get_dataItems()[row]._element.cells[7].innerText);
                        if (remainingBalance > 0) {
                            if (row == 0) {
                                if((paidAmount+payingAmount)>=totAmount)
                                {
                                    remainingBalance = (paidAmount + payingAmount) - totAmount;
                                    grid.MasterTableView.get_dataItems()[row]._element.cells[5].innerHTML = totAmount;
                                }
                                else if ((paidAmount + payingAmount) <= totAmount) {
                                    remainingBalance = 0;
                                    grid.MasterTableView.get_dataItems()[row]._element.cells[5].innerHTML = payingAmount+paidAmount;
                                    break;
                                }
                            }
                            else {
                                if (remainingBalance > totAmount) {
                                    grid.MasterTableView.get_dataItems()[row]._element.cells[5].innerHTML = totAmount;
                                    remainingBalance = remainingBalance - totAmount;
                                }
                                else if(totAmount>=remainingBalance){
                                    grid.MasterTableView.get_dataItems()[row]._element.cells[5].innerHTML =  remainingBalance;
                                    remainingBalance = 0;
                                    break;
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                else {
                    for (var row = 0; row < grid.MasterTableView.get_dataItems().length ; row++) {
                        paidAmountHdn = parseFloat(grid.MasterTableView.get_dataItems()[row]._element.cells[7].innerText);
                        grid.MasterTableView.get_dataItems()[row]._element.cells[5].innerHTML = paidAmountHdn;
                    }
                }
            }
```